# React blueimp-load-image rescaling of uploaded image

Tags: reactjs, canvas, blueimp

I'm using the package blueimp-load-image package to load an image in my react application. The image should be resized and put into a canvas afterwards.

This is my code that handles the upload. It can only be an image.

```
  const handleImageUpload = e => {
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    if (file) {
      loadImage(
        file,
        img => {
          setImage(img);
          changeOffset(img);
        },
        {
          orientation: true,
          maxWidth: innerWidth,
          maxHeight: innerHeight,
          downsamplingRatio: 0.25,
          pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
          imageSmoothingEnabled: true,
          imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
          canvas: false,
          contain: true,
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

The img gets put into a state variable that gets shown in my canvas (I'm using a KonvaImage from react-konva for that). My problem is that if I don't use *pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio*, the image gets shown correctly, but the quality is poor. If I, however, use *pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio*, the picture is zoomed in.

If I log out the img inside the loadImage this is the output. The first one without pixelRatio, the second one with pixelRatio.

[image: Without pixelRatio]

[image: With pixelRatio]

This is what the image on the screen looks like (again first one without pixelRation, the second one with pixelRatio):

[image: Without pixelRatio]

[image: Without pixelRatio]

I hope somebody can help me with my problem. I would of course also be open for a different way of resizing the images if it works better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find solution for this?